# Replacing URI when using dynamic hosts in Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, dynamic

FYI - I suspect this has a very obvious/simple answer (I'm new to nginx)

I am using [dynamic upstreams](https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/) as part of my Nginx config. This means using variables in the `proxy_pass` directive, which instructs nginx to use a `resolver` instead of crashing/not-booting if an upstream has a problem (unknown host / not connectable).

However, this seems to also change handling of `proxy_pass` with a URI. Rather than replacing with the request URI with the URI specified in the `proxy_pass` directive, it appears to ignore the request URI. I'm searching for a method to preserve (or reproduce) the original behavior that allows me to continue using dynamic hosts.

I have attempted to create a minimal example config here:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-server.com;

    # My chosen DNS server (in this case, the Docker DNS)
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;

    # This works
    location / {
        set $upstream frontend:8080;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }

    # This does not work :-( 
    # The original URI (e.g. /api/users/tommy) is ignored, and 
    # all requests to api-server are directly to /api/
    location /api/ {
        set $upstream api-server:8002;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream/api/;
    }
}
```

One workaround is to drop the URI from the `proxy_pass` directive and have the upstream server listen on the exact URI needed. This is not ideal, as a core benefit of a gateway server is adding some flexibility to change things independently (rewriting URIs if needed)

For example,

```
    # This kind of works, but upstream must listen on /api 
    location /api {
        set $upstream api-server:8002;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) states that if you use variables in the `proxy_pass` directive **and** you specify a URI part, it will be passed upstream "as is".

You will need to capture the part of the URI you need to send upstream. Either use a regular expression `location` block, for example:

```
location ~ ^/api(.*)$ {
    set $upstream ...;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream$1;
}
```

Or use a `rewrite...break` to change the current URI, for example:

```
location /api {
    set $upstream ...;
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
}
```

Comment: Ouch, RTFM. Thanks or the tip on what I missed!